# Roulette with prizes algorithm

Tags: probability, roulette-wheel-selection

I have a list of roulette items.
F.e

```
[
   'id' => 1,
   'probability' => 50 // probability in %
],
[
   'id' => 2,
   'probability' => 20 // probability in %
],
[
   'id' => 3,
   'probability' => 10 // probability in %
],
[
   'id' => 4,
   'probability' => 5 // probability in %
],
[
   'id' => 5,
   'probability' => 1 // probability in %
];
```

So i need to write an algorithm that will describe behaviour of the roulette due to probabilities.

I have no ideas, can someone help me with an idea?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

I think if you study this you will get some Idea to write it yourself.

[Fitness proportionate selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection)